# Looking up the row number of a shared identifier in Excel, and counting the number of cells in that row that meet specific criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have a sheet that contains a lookup value in columns. I want Excel to look for each value in another sheet, and count the number of instances of a certain word in the row in which it found that value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps posting a small dataset together with your expected result would help clarify your query.

Answer (score 0):

`H1=COUNTIF(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,MATCH(G1,Sheet2!C:C,0)-1,0,50),"FindMe")`

filled down column H

This will

1. Grab the corresponding value in column G
2. find the row that has that value in column C of Sheet2.
3. Count the number of times "FindMe" appears in that row.

   - The 50 is how many columns to search.
   - Change the $A$1 to $J$1 or whatever column you want to start searching in